# Как передать значения переменной в другую сцену unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь передать значение переменной времени из одной сцены в другую, но тут у меня выбивает ошибку NRE (NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TimeSave.Start () )

код 1 (TimeSave)

```
public float Timer;
private StartTimer time;

void Start() {
   time = gameObject.GetComponent<StartTimer>();
   Timer = time.Timer;
}
```

код 2 (StartTimer)

```
public float Timer;

public void Update()
{        
    Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    Timer = (float)System.Math.Round(Timer, 2);
    TimerText.text = "TIME: " + Timer.ToString() + " Sec"; 
}
```

как можно передать значение времени из одной сцены в другую?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает потому что вы пытаетесь воспользоваться переменной, значение которой равно null. Речь очевидно про `gameObject.GetComponent<StartTimer>();`

Для сохранения обьекта при изменении сцены можно воспользоваться методом `DontDestroyOnLoad(Object target);`